# How to show S is denumerable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm kind of confused as to where to start. Here's the problem: Given $S$ so that $|S|=|\mathbb{N}|$. Show there is a proper subset of $S$, $T$, such that $|S|=|T|$

Comment: Please write the problem into the body of the question. Also, we require you to provide some context for your problem. Even if you don't know where to start with the problem, you can talk about your understanding of the concepts involved. For instance, do you know what "denumerable" means here? (It's ok to say "no".)

Comment: Post please this question and show your attempts.

Comment: The title and the content are entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but here it goes the "usual" proof, pick an enumeration of $S=\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N} \}$, then $T=\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N},i>0 \}=S-\{x_0\}$, then $f:S\rightarrow T,$ $f(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ is a bijection and $T$ is a proper subset of $S$